# Dynamic Form set required and read only for the same field

Tags: dynamic-forms

I have a field Company

I would like to config this field in dynamic form as:

- Read only if user has profile like standard user
- Required if user has profile like system administrator.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic form, Field `UI behavior` can be applicable for entire UI in the page. So you need try **Required** behavior via `Validation Rule` for `System Admin` profile users as follows,

```
$User.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' & ISBlank(Company)
```

**Error:** Admins need to fill company details before save (like)

And for **READ Only** behavior, You can able to do that in profile level `field permission` settings.

Please let me know it helps.